# How can I encrypted aws ec2 volume using asymmetric keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need my aws volume to be encrypted using asymmetric keys , so that even root user cannot access that volume.

Can we do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not from AWS level, as EBS only supports symmetric encryption. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/services-ebs.html):

> Amazon EBS supports **only symmetric CMKs**. You cannot use an asymmetric CMK to encrypt an Amazon EBS volume.

You have to use third-party tools for that from the instance level.

Comment: what tools can be used? @Marcin

Comment: @PratikGehlot You can have a look at [dm-crypt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system), but I don't know if its supports asymmetric encryption.